# Application help and tutorial implementation

Tags: flutter

I would like to implement a interactive help for the new users of an application.

Kind of help, that greys out most of the screen, highlights a button and shows a text to explain what it does.

Has anyone implemented such a thing in flutter? Is there a plugin for that that I missed? Googling with "guide" or " tutorial" keyword just brings tutorials about flutter, not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

*I think you are looking for this `package`*

[Link For the Package](https://pub.dev/packages/tutorial_coach_mark)